# How to use command line parameter passed to msi when referencing IIS Web Site

Tags: iis, web, wix, windows-installer

As part of a bootstrapper system that I am using, I am creating an MSI using WiX that is called in the following manner:

```
msiexec /i product.msi WEBSITENAME="Default Web Site" PORT="80"
```

The WEBSITENAME and PORT parameters indicate the name of the website and port that was created as an earlier part of the bootstrapper system I am using.  Within my *.wxs file I would like to be able to use these passed in parameters in order to get a "reference" to the website so that I can create additional web applications, virtual directories, etc under this same website.

I have been able to do this by "hard-coding" the existing Web Site Name and port, i.e.

```
<!-- Reference existing Default Web Site at port 80 -->
<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="Default Web Site">
    <iis:WebAddress Id="MySiteWebAddress" Port="80"/>
</iis:WebSite>

<!-- Reference existng Default Application Pool -->
<iis:WebAppPool Id="DefaultApplicationPool" Name="DefaultAppPool">
</iis:WebAppPool>
```

and then using these hardcoded values to create the Virtual Directory in the below

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="MyVirtualDir" Alias="Images" Directory="ImagesDirectory" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="MyWebSiteApplication" Name="ImagesWebSite" WebAppPool="DefaultApplicationPool"/>
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```

What I would like to do now is replace the hard coded "Default Web Site" with the value passed in to the command line.

Is this possible?  If so how?  I have done some reading about using Properties, but I don't see how I would replace the hard coded string with the property.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enclose the name of the property in square brackets to force WiX to resolve it as a property. For example:

```
<iis:WebAppPool Id="WebAppPool" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_NAME]" Identity="other" User="WebAppPoolUser" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated"/>

<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="[WEBSITE_NAME]" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" AutoStart="yes" StartOnInstall="yes">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[WEBSITE_PORT]" Header="[WEBSITE_HEADER]"/>
  <iis:WebApplication Id="Application" Name="App" WebAppPool="WebAppPool" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

The 'Directory' attribute does not need brackets because it's already going to be resolved automatically, as explained [in the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/website.html).